# passing associative array to view and accessing values in it using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code in controller...

```
function print_dm($delivery_memo_id){
    $data1=array();

    $query=$this->db->query("select de.*, pr.* from phppos_delivery_memo de inner join 
    phppos_productdetails pr  on de.delivery_memo_id=pr.delivery_memo_id WHERE 
     de.delivery_memo_id=$delivery_memo_id");

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
  foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {

    $data1[]=$row->product_id;
    $data1[]=$row->product_name;
    $data1[]=$row->quantity;
    $data1[]=$row->unit;
    $data1[]=$row->unit_rate;


  }
}
else
{
$data1 = array();
 }

 $this->load->view('delivery_memo/print_layout',$data1);

}
```

When I print_r $data1 I get this..

```
 Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Zinc Sulphate [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 100 [5] => 4 [6] => Copper 
 Sulphate [7] => 1 [8] => 12 [9] => 100 [10] => 9 [11] => Sulphur 80% WDG [12] => 1 [13] => 1 
 [14] => 100 )
```

I pass it to view as above. But how do I access it there or should I change the code in controller??

**I am getting multiple records in that array**

Comment: `foreach($data1 as $data) echo $data;` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: undefined vaariable $data1

Comment: That means that you didn't passed the variable to the view!

Comment: I passed variable as above

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($data1);` in your view? if not you didn't passed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass query result to view:

```
function print_dm($delivery_memo_id){
    $data1=array();

    $query=$this->db->query("select de.*, pr.* from phppos_delivery_memo de inner join 
    phppos_productdetails pr  on de.delivery_memo_id=pr.delivery_memo_id WHERE 
     de.delivery_memo_id=$delivery_memo_id");

    $this->load->view('delivery_memo/print_layout', array('data1' => $query->result()));
}
```

Then you should be able to access your `$data1` variable in view, for example:

```
<?php foreach ($data1 as $row) { echo $row->product_id . "\n"; } ?>
```

Comment: Can you expalain me little bit ??

Comment: @KedarB When you pass data array to `view()` method, every key in it becomes a variable in the view. Since query `result()` is already something you can work with in a view, you just pass it to the `view()` method with key `'data1'` and in view you get variable `$data1`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you don't understand how to access data which passed to a view. You're passing an array to your view, there won't be `$data1` variable in a view, there will be vars which are named like keys in your passed array. So you should pass you data like this:

```
$this->load->view('delivery_memo/print_layout',array('data1' => $data1));
```

After that `$data1` will be accessible in a view:

```
var_dump($data1);
```

More on views here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: How do I access $data1 in view??

Comment: `var_dump($data1);` in a view file.